# Display only one div at a time with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am just fooling around with some JavaScript, I am new to it so this is probably a simple solution. Basically what I want is for only 1 `div` to be visible at a time so if a user clicks on one link to expose a `div` the current `div` that is exposed will collapse and the new one clicked will appear.

I have included the code below:

```
<html> 
    <head>

        <title> test</title>
        <LINK href="blah.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function toggle2(showHideDiv, switchTextDiv) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
    var text = document.getElementById(switchTextDiv);
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "restore";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "collapse";
    }
}
    function toggle22(showHideDiv2, switchTextDiv2) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv2);
    var text = document.getElementById(switchTextDiv2);
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "restore";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "collapse";
    }
}


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainContent">    
<div id="headerDiv">
     <div id="titleText">Change Password - Click here ==></div><a id="myHeader" href="javascript:toggle2('myContent','myHeader');" >restore</a>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div id="contentDiv">
     <div id="myContent" style="display: none;">This is the content that is dynamically being collapsed.</div>

<!--DIV2 -->

<div id="headerDiv2">
     <div id="titleText2">Change Username - Click here ==></div><a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:toggle22('myContent2','myHeader2');" >restore</a>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div id="contentDiv2">
     <div id="myContent2" style="display: none;">This is the content that is dynamically being collapsed.</div>




</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
#headerDiv, #contentDiv {
float: left;
width: 510px;
}
#titleText {
float: left;
font-size: 1.1em;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 5px;
}
#myHeader {
font-size: 1.1em;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 5px;
}
#headerDiv {
background-color: #0037DB;
color: #9EB6FF;
}
#contentDiv {
background-color: #FFE694;
}
#myContent {
margin: 5px 10px;
}
#headerDiv a {
color: gold;
float: right;
margin: 10px 10px 5px 5px;
}
#headerDiv a:hover {
color: #FFFFFF;
}




#headerDiv2, #contentDiv2 {
float: left;
width: 510px;
}
#titleText2 {
float: left;
font-size: 1.1em;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 5px;
}
#myHeader2 {
font-size: 1.1em;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 5px;
}
#headerDiv2 {
background-color: #0037DB;
color: #9EB6FF;
}
#contentDiv2 {
background-color: #FFE694;
}
#myContent2 {
margin: 5px 10px;
}
#headerDiv2 a {
color: gold;
float: right;
margin: 10px 10px 5px 5px;
}
#headerDiv2 a:hover {
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`style.display` only reflects the style that's been explicitly set on the element. Unless you specify it with `style="display:block"` in HTML, the initial value of `style.display` will be empty, even though the default value of that property, applied by CSS cascading, is indeed `block`.